# How can I call the overrided methods of a specific object?

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

Lets say I have a typical hierarchy like this:

[image]

What I want is to have a specific move() implementation for every class. So if I have the next code:

```
List<Vehicle> vehicles = GetVehicles();
foreach (Vehicle v in vehicles) 
{
    v.move(); 
}
```

The call to has to be made to the corresponding move() implementation depending on the class of v in runtime

I tried with virtual and override but if I call move() in a RedCar instance, it jumps to Car.move() (I guess this is because is the next override under Vehicle)

Any clue how can be done?

Comment: [Polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx). So override should be fine. Show us the code.

Comment: What you've proposed should work. Show some code that demonstrates the problem you're having instead of just an outline?

Comment: I'm betting you forgot the `override` keyword for your `RedCar.move()` method declaration. This considers it as its own separate method disassociated with the base `virtual Vehicle.move()`. EDIT: Visual Studio might be warning you about this with a green squiggily under the method declaration saying something to the effect of "move() is not overriding but hiding the methods. If this was intended add the `new` keyword."

Comment: just make move() abstract in Vehicle then implement them(with the override keyword) in the derived classes.

Comment: Add the class definitions. That would help everyone to see the exact problem. What you mentioned should not happen. As @Chris Sinclair said you must have forgot override.

Comment: My apologies, I tried with a really simple code and works as expected. I have to review my original code to find the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample code which works. I had this code handy so thought of posting it.

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public virtual void Move()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Vehicle Moving");
    }
}
public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public override void Move()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Car Moving");
    }
}

public class RedCar : Vehicle
{
    public override void Move()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Red car Moving");
    }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var vehicles = new List<Vehicle>
            {
                new RedCar(), new Car(),new Vehicle()
            };
        foreach (var vehicle in vehicles)
        {
            vehicle.Move();
        }
    }
}
```